# Most efficient way to add class for touch support

Tags: javascript, performance, touch

While working with styles and markup for a website I ran across places where on the desktop I would want to make the navigation menu items larger only when the user is on a device that supports touch, otherwise the users only option is to use a mouse. Currently for the checking for the support I am doing...

```
<html lang="en-us" class=" touchable">

<script type="text/javascript">
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
if(!is_touch_device){document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.replace(' touchable','')}
</script>

<head>
```

Which will remove the class of touchable when it is not touching is not supported. But I keep debating my method since I do currently  having it sit right after html tag to get removed more quickly if touch is not found. Besides moving it possibly one line below to the head section would anyone have any suggestions for making it better.

Thanks